# dynamic_cast and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, dynamic-cast, rvalue

```
class A{
public:
    virtual ~A() {};
};

class B : public A{ };

int main(){

    A&& p = B();

    dynamic_cast<B&&>(std::move(p));

}
```

Throws the error (g++ 5.2.0):

```
error: conversion to non-const reference type 'std::remove_reference<A&>::type& {aka class A&}' from rvalue of type 'A' [-fpermissive]
```

It attempts to cast `std::move(p)` to type `A&`, but I cannot figure out why. I would've thought it necessary to cast `p` as an rvalue before converting to an rvalue reference, but if I remove `std::move` it compiles fine. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

> `dynamic_cast < new_type > ( expression )`
>
> Similar to other cast expressions, the result is:
>
> an lvalue if new_type is an lvalue reference type (expression must be an lvalue)
>
> an xvalue if new_type is an rvalue reference type (**expression may be lvalue or rvalue**)

Even 5.2.7 of N3337:

> `dynamic_cast<T>(v)`
>
> If T is a pointer type, v shall be a prvalue of a pointer to complete class type, and the result is a prvalue of type T. If T is an lvalue reference type, v shall be an lvalue of a complete class type, and the result is an lvalue of the type referred to by T. **If T is an rvalue reference type, v shall be an expression having a complete class type, and the result is an xvalue of the type referred to by T**.

The only requirement there being that I use a complete class type, which `std::move(p)` is, isn't it?

Comment: Clang has no problems with your code

Comment: Confirmed with gcc 5.3. Works without the `std::move` call, though. ;)

Comment: ...as you noted in your question. I should read questions more thoroughly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is, of course, fine:

> If `T` is an rvalue reference type, `v` shall be an expression having a
>   complete class type, and the result is an xvalue of the type referred
>   to by `T`.

Presumably, `dynamic_cast` wasn't updated properly when rvalue references were introduced, and still enforces the pre-C++11 rule that rvalues shall only be bound to `const` lvalue references (note that it doesn't even work when altering the target type to `B const&&`, despite that being implied by the error message!).

Filed as [#**69390**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69390).

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work instead:

```
B&& b = std::move(dynamic_cast<B&>(p));
```

Can't tell you why yours is incorrect.